# Retrofit Dynamic JSON response

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, dialogflow-es

I'm new to JSON handling with retrofit but I've run into a problem.
We're making a prototype smart assistant chatbot with Dialogflow.

My Android Client sends a POST request to Google Dialogflow, which will call third party API's and send a response back.

However, this response depends on the type of intent detected by Dialogflow.
It can be nearly everything from music to weather information etc.
So the parameters (for the visualization) will be completely different and I don't know the type of response in advance.

I preprocess the response from Dialogflow in my own cloud function and send it back containing only the necessary fields for the client.

For example:

"What is the weather today in Brussels?"

Response:

```
{
    "sessionId": "123456789",
    "keepAlive": true,
    "intentId": 100,
    "intentName": "Weer",
    "text": "Het weer in Hanoi is helder met een temperatuur van 23.2 graden.",
    "Parameters": {
        "text": {
            "stringValue": "helder",
            "kind": "stringValue"
        },
        "city": {
            "stringValue": "Hanoi",
            "kind": "stringValue"
        },
        "temp": {
            "numberValue": 23.2,
            "kind": "numberValue"
        },
        "intentId": {
            "numberValue": 100,
            "kind": "numberValue"
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the Parameters of the response depend on the type of intent(id). there can be many or zero parameters depending on the intent.

How can I make a Pojo for every type of response, not only the weather?

Or can I make a switch case based on intentId or something?

Comment: You don't even know if its weather or music when you are requesting the data?

Comment: No that's the problem :) Dialogflow will use NLP to detect what the query means and then form a response. So I don't know what to expect in advance.

Comment: What JSON parsing lib are you using?

Comment: Gsonconversionfactory for retrofit 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics than

```
public class Response<T> {
       private String responseId;
       private String sessionId;
       private boolean keepAlive;
       private float intentId;
       private String intentName;
       private String text;
       private String Audio;
       private T Parameters;
        }
```

and when you want to create the object you can

```
new Response<YourClass>();
```

Your class will be the class as per your intent id

Comment: Unfortunately, the response isn't a simple key value pair as mentioned in my original post but a nested object who's key-name depends on the type of date. It's a horrible api.

Comment: do you know all the structure of all the coming nested objects

Comment: If I know the intentId, I know what fields the response will have. So I was wondering if I could do a switch case before the JSON is converted to an object.

Comment: You have to use generics in that case and in as per the intent id make the object as I have updated the answer